# persist() difference between spark 2.0.2 and spark 2.2.0+

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, persistence

With spark 2.0.2, doing ...

```
val parent: DataFrame = ...
parent.persist()
parent.count

val child: DataFrame = parent.filter(...)
child.persist()
child.count

parent.unpersist()
```

... does not unpersist the `child` dataframe. However, it does with spark 2.2.0 and spark 2.3.0 (maybe it does too with 2.1 ? I did not try) !

Is there an alternative to reproduce the `persist` from spark 2.0.2 but with newer versions of spark ? I've tried `checkpoint` but performances were not great.